# Remove a url segment with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My current url is

`http://foo.com/{first_parameter}/{second_parameter}`

Now I want to redirect it to

```
http://foo.com/{second_parameter}
```

How can I do it using htaccess ?

N.B: I'm using apache server

Comment: You want to completely loose the first parameter??? Is that wise???

Comment: Also have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ /$2 [R=301,L]
```

You can see it working [here](https://htaccess.mwl.be?share=a3c0d588-68e9-5f7d-bf4c-8e96319f26d3):